# How should I handle one extra bit of information of an object?

Tags: properties

I have two classes: `Employee` and `Conversation`.

`Conversation` has a property with the employees which participate in the conversation: `List<Employee> Participants { get; set; }`.

On the database, I store for each participant, whether or not there are messages in the conversation he didn't read yet.

**How should I store this information in the code?**

---

Here are the options I can think of:

1. Using an array. The array contains an `Employee` and a boolean value
   that indicates whether or not the employee read all the messages. So
   I would have a `List<object[2]>` (or something like that, never mind
   the syntax). The problem with this approach is that
   `List<object[2]>` is not very clear. I need to read the code to
   understand what it represents.
2. Using a `Dictionary<Employee, bool>`, which is clearer than an
   array. The     problem is that usually when I think of a
   `Dictionary` I think about a *real* dictionary with words and
   definitions, and here I really want to use it for storing something
   extra, not defining the key.
3. Simply creating a class `Participant : Staffer` which has one more property `bool ReadAll { get; set; }` and in `Conversation` simply having a `List<Participant>` property. This seems the most reasonable way, but I'm not sure if it worth to create a new type for such a small task.

One of them? Other option? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your third option is probably the best one, simply because **it aligns the code with the real world**. Creating a new type to model something that actually exists in the real world makes your code clearer and so much easier to understand.

Note that 'participant' does not necessarily have to *extend* from employee, a participant could simply contain a reference to Employee.

Comment: But a participant IS an employee.

Comment: @Sipo Would it be allright to pass a Participant to any method that takes an Employee? That's what you're communicating by subclassing. However, if your intention is to use Participant only within the context of a Conversation and having Participants passed to methods outside that context should not happen, then perhaps extending Employee is not beneficial after all.

Comment: @COMEFROM - You are right. I do not want to be able to pass Participant as an employee. So how would you implement it otherwise? Having a property of type `Employee`?

Comment: @Sipo Yes, by having an Employee -property. That would be quite the standard alternative to subclassing: using composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: @COMEFROM - I tried this solution, and it works very nice. But I am having a small "problem" that really annoys me. I have a `Message` class that represent a message in the conversation, and it has a `Sender` property of type `Participant`. Since the `Employee` is a property of `Participant` I have weird lines like `message.Sender.Employee.FirstName` instead of `message.Sender.FirstName`. How to avoid that?

Comment: @Sipo Do you need to know about unread messages of a Participiant of a Conversation in the context of a Message? Perhaps the Participiant class should be used only in the context of a whole Conversation, not in the context of a single Message? Also, chaining getter calls is often not preferable. If there's a need to get the first name of the sender of a Message for some purpose, then perhaps there could be a method (not an attribute) in the Message class that reflects the purpose. Like message.InformalSenderName().

Comment: You are right. But I do not want the message to have a `Sender` of type `Employee` because `Participant` is much more understandable. Maybe the name "participant" is inappropriate?

Comment: @COMEFROM - Please check out my question, I forgot to tag you.

Comment: @Sipo I think the name of the variable (or attribute) is what matters there, not the name of the type. It denotes the role of an object. "Sender" is the role of an Employee object in the context of a Message. The name "Participiant" sounds just fine to me. "Participation" could also work. It really doesn't matter that much if the type is used only in a very narrow scope. Btw, it seems you could ask a new question about the "message.Sender.Employee.Firstname"-problem to get more answers. Don't rely on my opinion only.